# Unittest : TypeError only with python-coverage

Tags: python

I'm a beginner with Python.

When I launch my test directly with

```
python3 src/testContent.py
```

All is OK. But when I use

```
python-coverage run src/testContent.py
```

I have a lot of new errors.
I could avoid some of them but now I have this TypeError but I don't understand why.
"TypeError: unbound method create() must be called with Content instant as first argument (got str instance instead)"

Here my code :

```
class TestContent(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_create(self):
        contentBrief = content.create('src/test.eml')
```

....

```
class Content:

        def create(path):
                fp = open(path, 'rb')
                msg = email.parser.BytesParser(policy=email.policy.default).parse(fp)
                body = msg.get_body(preferencelist=('plain')).get_content()
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is `content` (lowercase)?

Comment: What you show here is not an [mcve], but it sounds like you wrote something like `content = Content` rather than `content = Content(...)`.

Comment: Check if `python-coverage` uses python version 2.

Comment: Perhaps you have apt-installed python-coverage? apt-install `python3-coverage`.

Comment: Next step: read about virtual environments: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html